# "Thought about ending it"

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [a Youtube comment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mn0hZtVE04&lc=UgyrMuVQSoGM2QSnGOd4AaABAg) there's this personal story:

> I was going to Berklee back in the early 70's and I get a dear John over the phone. **Thought about ending it** but went down to the Jazz Workshop and there was Bill playing this Ballad. I went right up front and sat and cried my eyes out.

[sic]

I wonder whether "ending it" means

1. "**not going to the workshop**", i.e. a forward reference
2. or perhaps even "**ending my life**", because of the separation of his relationship

Comment: It is impossible to say without more context, but I would first take it to mean ending the relationship.

Comment: @HotLicks He already got a *Dear John*, so hasn't the relationship already ended, for all intents and purposes? Regarding the context, there is not a lot more available - you can click the link to read the full comment, but I doubt it adds any more useful context.

Comment: It either means ending his life or ending his time at Berklee. I'm going to go with *ending his life.* It would not have any reference to the Jazz workshop.

Comment: Is 'Berklee' meant to be [Berkeley](https://www.berkeley.edu/)?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey No, Berklee means [Berklee College of Music](https://www.berklee.edu/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*End it*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/end+it+all) (or *end it all*) is an idiom that means to kill oneself.

Given that the commenter had received a [Dear John](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dear_John_letter) "breakup" communication and was subsequently crying, it stands to reason that he was . . . upset.

Since there is no reasonable antecedent for *it* in this context, one could assume the idiom is at play here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that this is in fact a set phrase!